# How to sort and then apply a limit filter in Elasticsearch

Tags: search, lucene, elasticsearch

I want to [sort](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/sort.html) the results according to a specific field AND THEN apply the [limit](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/limit-filter.html) filter.

A simple common example would be a SQL query like `select name from users order by name limit 100` would have returned the sorted results limited by 100.

I tried the same in Elasticsearch. However, this is not happening. It first applies the limits AND THEN sorts which is giving me undesired results. Can anyone point me what I am doing wrong ? This is the query I am currently using.

```
{
  "sort": [
    "full_name"
  ],
  "filter": {
    "limit": {
      "value": 100
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limit filter works on each shard first and then results are merged on one of the nodes. If you have more than one shard, that can produce interesting results. I think, as Gabbar already mentioned, what you are looking for is the "size" parameter.

Answer (score 5):

How about using "size" in ElasticSearch? http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/from-size.html